# how to access a private variable in php?

Tags: php, drupal, private, fatal-error

I tried all the tricks available in the net, but dont know why, i am not able to access the variable.. heres the snippet of class containing private variable:

```
class PANASONIC_PRICESHEET {

    public $models = array();
    public $options = array();       
    public $accessories = array();    

    private $identifier = '';
    private $name = '';
    private $currency1 = '€';
    private $currency2 = '£';

    /**
     * 
     */        
    public function __construct($name1 = 'unnamed', $identifier1 = '') {
        $this->name = $name1;
        $this->identifier = $identifier1;
    }

    public function getIdentifier() {
        return $this->identifier;       
    }

    /**
     * 
     */        
    public function getName($withIdentifier = false) {       
        if ($withIdentifier) {
            return $this->name . " - " . $this->identifier;
        } else {
            return $this->name;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how i am accessing it:

```
$thisName = $pricesheet->getName();
$thisIdentifier = $pricesheet->getIdentifier();
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot access private property PANASONIC_PRICESHEET::$name in
C:\AppServ\www\dashboard\sites\all\modules\_custom\pricing_system\pricing_system.inc
on line 316
```

How to fix this? I cannot make the field PUBLIC, its not a option at all. Any suggestions please.

## EDIT - 1

Issue has been solved:
I was suppose to call $_pricesheet->getName();
thanks a lot for suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure this is all the code, which produces that error?

Comment: What @Shef says - is that really the code that is causing the error?

Comment: Line 316, is that one of the two you have put up for accessing it?  Or one of the lines of the class?  As there are definitely not 316 lines up there.

Comment: yes, this is the code where i am accessing the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently working for me. Take a look [here](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/982f8/2). You must be probably trying to access `$pricesheet->name;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call a private Function in your Public function which returns the private Variable.
Similar to Closures in Javascript.

Hope it works